# display radiobutton based on particular dayname in php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

I am trying to display radio button based on particular dayname selected in the textbox. I have created a table days which stores dayname, and description. When you select the date from the datepicker it extracts a dayname and based on the dayname I want to fetch the values were the dayname is selected value. For eg if the selected date is 13-05-2018 it will display day as sun, events which are on sun as to display in radio button or a select option dynamically. 
Here is the code.

```
  $(function() {
  var date = new Date();
  var dayNo = date.getDay();
  var mindate = (7 - dayNo);
  var d = ['sun', 'mon', 'tue', 'wed', 'th', 'fr', 'sat'];
  var event = ['test1', 'Test2']
var event1 = ['test2', 'Test2']
  //Lest assume this is  event from database
  $("#datepicker").datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
    firstDay: 1,
    minDate: mindate,
    onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
      var today = new Date(dateText);
      var a = (d[today.getDay()]);
      $('#slDay').val(d[today.getDay()])
      var html = '';
      $('#slDay').html('');
     if ((d[today.getDay()] =='sun'){
      $.each(event, function(index, value) {

        html += '<option value="' + value + '">' + value + '</option>'
      });
```

});
          $('#slDay').append(html);

```
    });
  });
});
</script>

<input type="text" id="datepicker">
<input type="text" id="datepicker1" name="datepicker1">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `dropdown` id and append.I create snippet for option

```js
$(function() {
  var date = new Date();
  var dayNo = date.getDay();
  var mindate = (7 - dayNo);
  var d = ['sun', 'mon', 'tue', 'wed', 'th', 'fr', 'sat'];
  var event = ['test1', 'Test2'] //Lest assume this is  event from database
  $("#datepicker").datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
    firstDay: 1,
    minDate: mindate,
    onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
      var today = new Date(dateText);
      var a = (d[today.getDay()]);
      $('#slDay').val(d[today.getDay()])
      var html = '';
      $('#slDay').html('');
      if (d[today.getDay()] == 'sun')
        $.each(event, function(index, value) {
          html += '<option value="' + value + '">' + value + '</option>'
        });
      $('#slDay').append(html);
    }

  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="datepicker">

<select id='slDay'>

</select>
```

Comment: Not like this. If selected day from datepicker  is sun the list of events available on sun as to be display in the dropdown. There will be multiple events available on particular day

Comment: Where is list of element  to display? If they are in database you need to call ajax and bind your data on dropdown.

Comment: It should fetch the value from db or whether if possible from jquery. for eg  If available events on sun are games,singing etc and it as to be in dropdown or radio button. It as to change the events  when selected day is different

Comment: See updated answer similar for radio button condition check what to append depend on your logic. .

Comment: If the selected day  mon the events as to be changes to test3,test4. Based on daynames events as to be changed

Comment: Yap . I add a comment where to check for condition see update.

Comment: I tried adding comment it doesnt display the datepicker itself. I have updated the script.